# Kogito Boundary Error and Catch All Subprocess together

Tags: kogito

I have a node within my kogito workflow with a boundary error for a  specific type of exception (e.g. BusinessException), and a separate catch all subprocess that should deal with all other exception types that are thrown. (currently configured to catch Throwable).

I would like to handle BusinessExceptions, e.g. CreditCardBlacklisted via Boundary errors.

However, when the node throws the CreditCardBlacklistedException, the boundary error is ignored and the catch all event subprocess is initiated.

[Picture Of Workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgZXE.png)

How can I get this scenario to work so that when CreditCardBlacklistedException is thrown it goes to the Handle Blacklisted node and not the catch all sub process?

Comment: Hi! Can you kindly share a reproducer?

Comment: Hi, I raised a JIRA to RedHat - https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KOGITO-8191 reproducer is attached as zip to this ticket

Answer (score 0):

Fixed in the JIRA issue [KOGITO-8191](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KOGITO-8191) to be released in version 1.31.0.Final.